# MySQL Display 4th smallest value for each team

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using phpMyAdmin on MySQL 5.7
The code below selects the lowest values excluding any zero values and gives me a nice table of all the teamids with the lowest times in seconds next to them for that event (zid).

```
SELECT teamid, MIN(time) AS 'fastest time'
FROM data
WHERE time > 0 AND zid = 217456
GROUP BY teamid
```

How do I adapt it to get the 4th lowest values?
I have tried countless suggestions found via searching but none work

Table Headings:
id (AI column set as Primary Index)
zid (this is an event identification number)
teamid
name
time (given in seconds)

I could add a position in team column which would make this very easy? Then I just ask MySQL to get me all the positions = to 4 ?

Comment: @Martien Carew, I am outside, can just give you hints for now, try MySQL variable or inner subquery but make sure to handle multiple occurrence of same instance per team.

Comment: It would be great if you can share `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and sample data as `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Share sample data too, export a small subset of your data from table and send as `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @JitendraYadav - No need for `INSERT`, why are you asking for that?

Comment: For guys like me, who wants to provide you a solution, so we can import data at our local and can replicate same to write queries.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. It's up to you whether you want to follow the advice at the accepted answer there, but if you choose not to, please don't '@' me!

Comment: Search for mysql row number

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you, it's a very good link for beginner to know, how things should be asked. Will use it for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MySQL 8**: Use Window functions.

- [Dense Rank](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank)
- [Window Function Concept & Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)

```
SELECT 
    teamid, 
    time '4th_Lowest'
FROM data
WHERE time > 0 AND zid = 217456
    AND (dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY teamid ORDER BY time ASC)) = 4;
```

**Mysql 5.7 and Lower**: We will use following variables to calculate this on the sorted data(teamid and then time)

- `rank` - to set rank for each unique(teamid, time)
- `c_time` - whenever there is a change between `time` of two consecutive rows, we will increase the rank. `IF(@c_time = d.time, @rank, @rank:= @rank + 1)`
- `c_team_id` - we will check whether two consecutive rows have same or different team, if different then reset rank to 1. Check else part **IF(@c_team_id = d.teamid, ...,`@rank:= 1`)**

```
SELECT 
    t.teamid,            
    t.`time`              
FROM(
    SELECT 
        d.teamid,           -- Represent current row team id
        d.`time`,           -- Represent current row time
        IF(@c_team_id = d.teamid, IF(@c_time = d.`time`, @rank, @rank:= @rank + 1), @rank:= 1) as rank,  -- determine rank based on above explanation.
        @c_team_id:= d.teamid,  -- We are setting this variable to current row team id after using it in rank column, so rank column of next row will have this row team id for comparison using @c_team_id variable.
        @c_time:= d.`time`
    FROM `data` AS d,
    (SELECT @c_time:= 0 as tim, @c_team_id:= 0 as tm_id, @rank:= 0 as rnk) AS t
    WHERE d.`time` > 0 AND d.zid = 217456
    ORDER BY d.teamid, d.`time` ASC   -- Use to make sure we have same team records in sequence and with ascending order of time.
) AS t
WHERE t.rank = 4
GROUP BY t.teamid;
```

Comment: Also solutions by Islingre would work too. You can check them too.

Comment: That works beautifully! Now to spend some time understanding it. One thing to note that the times are rarely the same but if they are the same, they still get ranked  consecutively. The teams are frequently mixed up and dont all finish together but usually the front 4 are together (its a bike race where the 4th bike sets the teams time)

Comment: @MartinCarew, Even times are same, it will handle it properly, see my `c_time` explaination, it says only if two consecutive times will change than only we will increase rank. Notice that `ORDER BY` clause and `IF` condition in select statement.

Comment: @MartinCarew, added some explanation to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your version supports window-functions (since 8.0):

```
SELECT teamid, time 'fourth_time'
FROM data
WHERE time > 0
    AND zid = 217456
    AND (dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY teamid ORDER BY time ASC)) = 4
```

**EDIT**: `dense_rank` seems to fit better, it will give the fourth-best time now, ignoring multiple appearances of the best to third-best times. The earlier version used `row_number`, not ignoring multiple apperances. Thanks for mentioning in the comments.

Comment: That looked like it should work but is throwing up an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (PARTITION BY teamid ORDER BY time ASC)) = 4 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5

Comment: Since the problem occurs at the ```OVER```: what is your mysql version? I guess it should work this way, so I assume your version is older than 8.0? If not, I might try it again. But if, your DB does not support window-functions yet..

Comment: Checked version - it is v5.7 so not supporting windows functions

Comment: That is sad... I gonna give you another answer with a ```LIMIT```, if you give me a minute

Comment: That would be great. If you need any more info about the table 'data' please ask - I am here.

Comment: See the other answer. The PK is in question, but I hope it is sure to assume, that there is one. If not, put your full table description in the question, perhaps I gonna adjust it

Comment: @Islingre, this will not give you nth highest, if you have multiple records for same time. Let's say you have two max records for a team then it will give to `n-1` record for the same.

Comment: Use `dense_rank` for the same, in MySQL 8, if you want to get proper answer.

Comment: Indeed, the behavior of dense_rank is more likely to be the expected one.. Thaks, I gonna make an edit

Answer (score 0):

Since your version does not support window-functions, you can use a subselect with a `LIMIT` (I assume you have a field `id`, that is a primary key. If your primary key is another field, just replace this. If there is more than one field in your primary key, you will need to check all of them):

```
SELECT d.teamid, MIN(d.time) fourth_time
FROM data d
WHERE d.time > 0
    AND d.zid = 217456
    AND d.time > (SELECT t.time
                  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT d2.time
                         FROM data d2
                         WHERE d2.time > 0
                             AND d2.zid = 217456
                             AND d2.teamid = d.teamid
                       ) t
                  ORDER BY t.time ASC
                  LIMIT 1
                  OFFSET 2)
GROUP BY d.teamid
```

Comment: Same issue with this too. Try inner query to fetch ids of least 3 times for a team, if they can have multiple occurrence of time.

Comment: I think I need a newer version of MySQL! Another error message....This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: I am surprised, since the documentation for the version says it works.. [Docu](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Comment: See let's say you have 1 record of value 10, 2 records of 12 and 1 record of 13 and one record of 14 for a team. Check your subquery. It will exclude I'd of three records but it should exclude 4 records.

Comment: I meant the version problem, not yours ^^ You are right, for sure.. I gonna adjust it, I guess, at least I got an idea.

Comment: So perhaps this version might also run on v5.7. Since there is no more use of ```IN```. I just realised, that the error says the combination of ```LIMIT``` and the ```IN``` subquery is the problem. Did not check the manual for things lie this..

Comment: Actually, I found the page of the manual specifying the ```LIMIT```/```IN``` subquery problem. It is nicely hidden [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-errors.html)